# MS SQL Server 2008 - Duplicate records "rank" of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Good afternoon,

I would like to know if there is a simpler way of performing this function. What I need to do is create a column that a user can sum up for use in multiple calculations. I would normally use a Distinct Count in the front end app (such as SSRS or PowerView) to display what I need, however since this is designed for self service, the people using the data will not completely understand.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
SELECT *
, [ROW] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY T.REQUEST_ID
    )
, [CT_DIS] = CAST(CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY T.REQUEST_ID ORDER BY DT
                ) = 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS INT)
FROM testdata as t
```

I do have some test data to work with; however I cannot get the fiddle to tune properly. 
The column that I need examined is [CT_DIS].

This works perfectly quick enough with a simple query, however, the one that this really needs to go into is a very large query that has multiple CTEs pulling data out of Oracle thru a linked server, and nearly 70k rows (growing by about 300-600 daily). The problem is performance. I suppose a final solution would be to bring the data over thru SSIS and have CT_DIS run afterwards.

Does a function exist that returns the same result and with faster response?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think there's a more effective query than the one you have above, but that query's performance could likely be improved, either by indexing or by changing the process as you suggest.

Comment: You could try using a `LEFT JOIN (SELECT REQUEST_ID, MIN(DT) MinDT FROM testdata GROUP BY REQUEST_ID) X ON t.REQUEST_ID = X.REQUEST_ID AND t.DT = X.MinDT`, and your `[CT_DIS]` column would be: `CASE WHEN X.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @Lamak Have you ever seen an instance where adding a `JOIN` and an aggregate is faster than using analytic functions on a single table?  I'm not sure I've ever encountered that, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: @GoatCO As the matter of fact, yes, I have, that's why I suggested to op to try and see if there is a difference in performance

Comment: @Lamak I guess I should have assumed that's why you suggested it, and asked rather if you could think of any specific situations where it's more performant.

Comment: @GoatCO No clear scenario comes to mind now. But since op says that the data comes from different CTEs and a linked server to Oracle, there's the possibility that the execution plan generated from the `LEFT JOIN` could be a better one for his/her scenario. Anyway, the best option would be to try the query and see. And because of my lack of clarity here is that I didn't post that as an answer

Comment: Update:  I moved the CT_DIS column into the one CTE that would benefit from it, and that has improved the performance. I am working on moving some of the other functions around, into the openquery statement and seeing if that helps performance more (as the Oracle server is a lot beefier than the MS/SQL and SSRS servers combined are) Thanks for your suggestions, I do appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I was able to work around the issue using a SSIS job to grab the data and load into report server level tables. Thanks for the help!